# Load all version dependency of same type using Mave

Tags: maven

I want to load both versions of hibernate-core classes using maven. But in my case Maven always loads 5.2.12.Final version dependency in my project. But I want use same class of version 3.5.0-Final. How can achieve I it?

Comment: Your question is not only bad-formatted but has contradictions: Do you want both versions (5.2.12 and 3.5.0), or only the latter; it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load more than one version of `hibernate-core`. You need to decide which version you want and then include it as dependency (or overwrite its version in dependencyManagement).